# OnBuffer event is not calling in react-native-video player

Tags: react-native, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, react-native-video

I am using **react-native-video** library.

I have added following line in **android/settings.gradle** to use exoplayer as mentioned in its docs.

```
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')
```

And I have

```
"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
```

The video player shows green seek bar and its **onBuffer** event does not fire. How do I confirm if I am using exoplayer or not in react native ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue on my own.

The settings in **android/settings.gradle** did not work for me. So I added **react-native.config.js** in root folder of the project and added following lines:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

***Note: Green track ball on seek bar means it's old media player. White track ball means it's exoplayer.***